# ThreadPoolExecutor Exception

Tags: android, threadpool

While using the application, I faced this exception. This happens not a specific situation. Sometimes opening a fragment, sometimes setting a text to textview. So I don't understand the problem properly.

Can you say anything about this?

This is the last exception log that I got

```
Task android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1@373f483 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@b9965c7[Running, pool size = 9, active threads = 9, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 31]

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2014)

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:794)

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1340)

android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor.scheduleNext(AsyncTask.java:247)

android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor.execute(AsyncTask.java:241)

android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:622)

android.widget.TextView.updateTextServicesLocaleAsync(TextView.java:8711)

android.widget.TextView.getTextServicesLocale(TextView.java:8658)

android.widget.TextView.getSpellCheckerLocale(TextView.java:8704)

android.widget.SpellChecker.<init>(SpellChecker.java:112)

android.widget.Editor.updateSpellCheckSpans(Editor.java:658)

android.widget.Editor.onAttachedToWindow(Editor.java:353)

android.widget.TextView.onAttachedToWindow(TextView.java:5262)

android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14520)

android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)

android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)

android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)

android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)

android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)

android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)

android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)

android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)

android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)

android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1364)

android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)

android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6007)

android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)

android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)

android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)

android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)

android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

my every thread calling like this, I don't use AsyncTask s

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                ...
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: can post one code example for better understand? It will be very helpful

Comment: Cloud you post code block caused exception? It'll be good for debugging.

Comment: @faysalneowaz There is no specific code part. This logs comes from users. I dont know the exactly scenerio, either.

Answer (score 0):

This is a RejectedExecutionException as I presume was thrown by execute() in AsyncTask.

This happens for two reasons:

1. Your thread pool is full (Which in this case it is as stated that 9/9 Threads are in use)
2. Your thread pool object is destroyed

Following your first reason you can handle your thread pool by waiting till one of the threads created finishes it's task before creating a new Thread via the get function:

```
execute().get();
```

Comment: Can you provide some more code. I have updated my answer. How can I use this execute().get();

Comment: Hi, from your edit, you can use something like a wait() to wait until the Thread execution finishes, the problem with this approach is that it's blocking your UIThread.

You should be using AsyncTask to have the Android Evironment handle it in the background for you, with more resources to give.